# How to receive emailed csv data into Google Cloud SQL

Tags: csv, google-cloud-sql

The goal is to set up a simple relational database in Google Cloud SQL (or BigQuery) that automatically receives/retrieves daily emailed reports. The data source, in this case, is Doubleclick but regardless of the source, I'd like to better understand how scheduled email reports (as attachments) can be sent to or ingested by Google Cloud SQL.

Is there some other app or service out there to make this connection? Is there a Google product like MS Visual Studio to run jobs? Sorry for the very beginner questions but none of the Google support articles are very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Google Apps Scripts to tie the process together.

App Scripts can [DoubleClick data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/doubleclick-campaigns) and potentially read from a [gmail account](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/).

Once you have access to the data, you should be able to use [BigQuery service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) in script to load the data

You can then create a scheduled project trigger within script to poll periodically for new files